# Zend 2 multiple layouts for 1 module setup

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am new @ Zend2.

I have now 2 layouts, both with for example see below.

layout/layout.phtml

layout/custum.phtml

What's the best way to "push" it once?

In the bootstrap?

```
<meta charset="<?php echo $charset; ?>">
```

Both awnsers are very usefull, thnx!

My choice is the header.phtml but the other one i am also going to use.

Comment: i have only one response: ha? .... it's very unclear what is it that u asking ...

Comment: @Exlord See above, 2 layouts with both <meta charset="<?php echo $charset; ?>"> How to generate it once

Comment: do u mean a reusable layout parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HeadMeta](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.head-meta.html#view-helper-headmeta) view helper can be used to render the HTML metatag.

```
// layout/header.phtml
$this->headMeta()->setCharset($charset);
echo $this->headMeta();
```

In terms of 'reusing it' you could use the above in a new view script, say `header.phtml` and include it in both layouts using the [ViewPartial](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html#view-helper-partial) plugin.

```
// In both layout.phtml files
echo $this->partial('layout/header.phtml', array('charset' => 'UTF-8'));
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand the question correctly, u can either use `partial` view helper 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial
or set a value to layout in bootstrap like this :

```
$this->bootstrap('layout');
$layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
$layout->getView()->assign('charset',"<meta charset='{$charset}'>");
```

and use it in the layout like a normal var : `$this->charset`